# Timeout value too small for a Recurring Billing transaction

Tags: paypal

We use PayPal for a subscription service and are seeing failed transactions in the recurring payments due to:

**Result Code:** 101
**Response Message:** Timeout value too small

This is not during the initial transaction when setting up the profile but later on once a payment is due (i.e. it's out of our hands.)

I wouldn't imagine the timeout value provided to PayflowConnectionData in the .NET API wrapper would be remembered for subsequent transactions would it? Stranger things have happened!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your API request to create the profile?

Comment: It's recommended to have the timeout set to "90". What do you have it set as currently?

Comment: This is for recurring billing. We do not / can not set the timeout.